# Scala plugin problem in eclipse for Spark

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

[image]       I am using eclipse ide for Scala and I have downloaded *scala-ide* plugin from eclipse marketplace. I am getting error while using scala plugin in eclipse. Following error message showing while using dot(.) or auto-generating functions in eclipse:

An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info".
        org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/JavaProject;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/WorkingCopyOwner;)

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import java.lang.Long

    object UrbanPopulation {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {
            val spark = SparkSession
                .builder
                .appName("UrbanPopulation")
                .getOrCreate()
            val data = spark.read.csv(args(0)).rdd
            val result = data.map { line => {
            val uPopulation = line.getString(10).replaceAll(",", "")
                var uPopNum = 0L
                    if (uPopulation.length() > 0)
                    uPopNum = Long.parseLong(uPopulation)
                    (uPopNum, line.getString(0))
            }}.sortByKey(false).first

   spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(result)).saveAsTextFile(args(1))
   spark.stop
        }
    }

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTGbp.png
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Eclipse bug [546156](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546156) which says that code completion for Scala is broken in Eclipse 2019-03 due to an incompatible change in Eclipe JDT.

The bug is marked as fixed in the first Milestone release of Eclipse 2019-06 (2019-06M1) planned for availability on 19 April 2019.